# VBA Excel Code - Windows Popup Open or Save

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working through potential answers to my question for some time with little success. I have found a lot of coding references seem to bypass the issue. So I decided to ask the question.

I have simple coding that will open a website, login, acess a specific report and then download the file in .xls. When I do this the windows popup appears to Open or Save the File.

What I need is to save the file to a specific location, for example c:\datatemp.xls

I cannot find a way to successfully achieve this.

This is my simple code:

```
Sub main()
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim user As String
  Dim pwd As String
  Dim stockrep As String
  Dim btn As Object

  user = Range("B1").Value 'This is the username derived from the sheet cell
  pwd = Range("B2").Value 'This is the password derived from the sheet cell
  stockrep = Range("B3").Value 'This is the http of the stock report file from the sheet cel

  'Now to open the website in Internet Explorer
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  ie.navigate Url
  ie.Visible = True

  'wait until the page loads
  Do While ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
  Loop

  'Now to enter the username and password, then click enter
  With ie.document
    .getElementById("userName").Value = user
    .getElementById("password").Value = pwd
    .getElementById("submitButton").Click
  End With

  'Pause while it loads
  Do While ie.readyState <> 4
   DoEvents
  Loop

  'Continue to the defined stock report page
  ie.navigate stockrep

  'Wait for the page to load
  Do While ie.readyState <> 4
   DoEvents
  Loop

  'Pause to allow the report to load and then click the download xls button
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:30"))
  Set btn = ie.document.getElementById("xlsbutton")
  btn.Click

  'This is as far as I have got. Need to click the Save As button, save to a set location,
  'open the file, select the cells, copy and paste, then close the 2nd doc and delete the file
End Sub
```

If I can simply get the coding to save as then I should be able to complete the rest. Any ideas?